# Condition in a mysql update for a numeric field if(DEFAULT)

Tags: mysql

Which value to set to 'default' if I want to keep the test ?

```
mysql> update softwareitem set SIMobsolescence = DEFAULT where SIMID =
2624553;
```

> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>   Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

```
mysql> update softwareitem set SIMobsolescence = if (1>2, 0, DEFAULT)
where  SIMID = 2624553;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') where SIMID = 2624553' at line 1

```
mysql> update softwareitem set SIMobsolescence = if (1>2, 0, 'DEFAULT') where SIMID = 2624553;
```

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'DEFAULT' for column 'SIMobsolescence' at row 1

```
mysql>
```

Comment: excuse me, `SIMobsolescence` int(11) DEFAULT '0',

Comment: did you try "DEFAULT(SIMobsolescence)" ?

Comment: thank you slash :)
mysql> update softwareitem set SIMobsolescence = if (1>2, 0, DEFAULT(SIMobsolescence)) where SIMID = 2624553;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql>

Answer (score 1):

So - to make it more readable -  the answer is to use the DEFAULT(col) function:

```
mysql> update softwareitem set SIMobsolescence = if (1>2, 0, DEFAULT(SIMobsolescence)) 
where  SIMID = 2624553;
```

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)